# AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'inet_aton'

Tags: python, sockets

When I run this scrip in terminal didn't work :/ , but when run that scrip on project pycharm it works without problems.
this my code :

```
import socket  
from binascii import hexlify   

def iphost():  

    for ip_addr in ['192.168.1.15','127.0.0.1']:  

       packed = socket.inet_aton(ip_addr)  

       unpacked = socket.inet_ntoa(packed)  

       print ('Ip address : %s = packed: %s , unpacked %s'%(ip_addr,hexlify(packed),unpacked))

iphost()
```

.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "socket.py", line 1, in <module>
      import socket
   File "/home/linuxmint/Desktop/socket.py", line 9, in <module>
      iphost()
   File "/home/linuxmint/Desktop/socket.py", line 5, in iphost
      packed = socket.inet_aton('192.168.1.15','127.0.0.1')
   AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'inet_aton'
```

this problem when run in terminal

Comment: Please share the error you are getting while running it in terminal

Comment: @Mr.Budris you don't need `main` to execute python script from the command line.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Thanks for the flag, misunderstood the question.  Removed my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You named your file `socket.py` so now `import socket` loads your file `socket.py` instead of python module - and it can't find `'inet_aton'` in your file.

Change name of your file - ie. `socket-example.py`

Comment: OP might also have to delete the file `socket.pyc`.

Comment: @Robᵩ maybe but in error message I see `File "/home/linuxmint/Desktop/socket.py"` so OP created `socket.py` on desktop.

Comment: Right - your diagnosis is 100% correct, and he certainly needs to rename `socket.py`. But after renaming `socket.py`, his problem might continue until he deletes `socket.pyc`.